# Ayuda con JasperReport, por que manda el siguiente error y no se visualiza?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jasper-reports

tengo el siguiente código en mi controlador, donde lo que regresa es el nombre de mi reporte `prueba_reporte`

```html
@RequestMapping("/report")
public String verReporte(Model model, @RequestParam(name = "format", defaultValue="pdf", required = false) String format{

 model.addAttribute("format", format);
 model.addAttribute("datasource", facturaService.consultaAll());
 model.addAttribute("autor", "Dev");

 return "prueba_reporte";
 
 
}
```

Este es mi código de mi jsp, donde tengo un botón que al dar click manda a llamar a una función que apunta a la url de mi método en mi controlador

```html
<script>
 function generarDocumento(){
  var data = "consultaForm";
  var url: "${pageContext.request.ContextPath}/report";
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: data,
  dataType: 'json',
  
  });
 
 }
</script>
<form id="consultaForm">

 <button type="button" onclick="generarDocumento();">GENERAR</button>

</form>
```

y esta es mi configuración, pero la verdad no entiendo bien a que se refiere cada método y por que el orden?, alguien podría explicarmelo

```html
@Bean
public ViewResolver configureViewResolver(){

 InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolve = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
 viewResolve.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
 viewResolve.setPrefix(Constants.PUBLIC_PREFIX);
 viewResolve.setSuffix(Constants.VIEW_SUFFIX);
 viewResolve.setOrder(2);
 return viewResolve;
}


@Bean
public ViewResolver publicViewResolver(){

 UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver = new ChainableUrlBasedViewResolver();
 viewResolver.setPrefix(Constants.PUBLIC_PREFIX);
 viewResolver.setSuffix(Constants.VIEW_SUFFIX);
 viewResolver.setOrder(1);
 return viewResolver;
}

@Bean
public  JasperReportsViewResolver getJasperReportsViewResolver(){

JasperReportsViewResolver resolver = new JasperReportsViewResolver();
resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/jasperreports");
resolver.setSuffix(".jasper");
resolver.setReportDataKey("datasource");
resolver.setViewClass(JasperReportsMultiFormatView.class);
resolver.setOrder(0);

return resolver;

}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que al  dar click en mi botón, me mande a otra pagina donde pueda visualizar mi reporte y descargarlo en pdf, mi reporte esta ubicado en la ruta:  `src/main/resources/jasperreports/prueba_reporte.jasper`

y al dar click en el boton sale el siguiente error

```html
Value [null] cannot be converted to a JRDataSource
y marca error en la clase:  JasperReportsUtils.java: 74
```

pero yo no encuentro esa clase,
alguien podría ayudarme?
o como mas puedo  implementar jasper reports?

Ojala puedan ayudarme, gracias!

Comment: ¿Tienes un archivo llamado jasper-views.xml?

Comment: No, no tengo ningún archivo asi